# Html elements not breaking page within the element value itself which leads to several half-empty pages

Tags: html, css, pdf, phantomjs

I am generating html from markdown using marked and use a slightly modified version of github-markdown-css which is installable via npm. Out of that html and css a pdf is generated using html-pdf.

I defined a style class, which has `page-break-inside: avoid` property. I need that e.g for message-headlines and the message itself, so that these 2 items are not seperated by page-breaks. Now the problem is that I then have huge empty areas before these groups because the page breaks before, but I actualy only need the `page-break-inside: avoid` between the headline and the message, not within the message itself.

How can I try to preserve the page-breaks within the message itself? I have already tried to use `page-break-after: avoid` for the headlines, but somehow it did not make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be

```
page-break-after: avoid;
```

for the subhead/title above the message (example):

```
<h style="page-break-after: avoid;">MESSAGE TITLE</h>
<p>My Message</p>
```

From what you are saying, it seems like you have an embracing element (`div`) with `page-break-inside:avoid`. Try separating it into smaller elements `<p>` and `<h>` with `page-break-before:avoid` and `page-break-after:avoid`

Comment: yeah that was my initial version, I just tried it again, and the problem is that even though my titles have a `page-break-after: avoid` the title itself stays at the half of the page while the image gets placed to the next page. I need the title to switch to the next page along with the image (my images have `page-break-before: avoid`)